# Redirecting unique values and timestamp differences to file using awk / sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I wonder if someone could give me some on a task i'm trying to do - I'm a bit of a newb! :(

I have a text file called "stream.txt" which has a number of fields separated by semicolons, and is in this format:

```
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222222;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222333;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222444;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222444;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222555;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222777;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
field1=xxx;field2=xxx;field3=111222888;field4=xxx;field5=xxx
```

What I'm looking to do is use awk/sed/grep to search for unique values of field3, and redirect them to another file called "differences.txt" with the difference in value between the field3 value and the previous value. In the case of the above example, I'm looking for the following output:

```
111222333    111
111222444    111
111222555    111
111222777    222
111222888    111
```

I'm OK searching for the values of field3 and redirecing them, but I'm finding it trick getting the differences between the value and the previous value to show next to it. Does anyone have any tips?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F';' '
    BEGIN{a=0} {gsub(/^.*=/,"",$3); 
    if(a>0 && $3-a>0){print $3,$3-a} a=$3}
  ' stream.txt > differences.txt

$ cat differences.txt
111222333 111
111222444 111
111222555 111
111222777 222
111222888 111
```

Brief explanation,

1. `gsub(/^.*=/,"",$3`: extract the numeric part of `$3`
2. `a`: is to store the difference
3. `if(a>0 && $3-a>0){print $3,$3-a}`: print if the difference is larger than 0

Comment: @villaman thanks, and if this did help you, please kindly check to accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'[;=]' '!($6 in keys){ a[++c]=$6; keys[$6] }
     END{ delete keys; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(a[i+1]) print a[i+1],a[i+1]-a[i] }' file > differences.txt
```

*Result*:

```
> cat differences.txt 
111222444 111
111222555 111
111222777 222
111222888 111
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
$ awk -F'[=;]' 'NR>1 && $6!=p{print $6, $6-p} {p=$6}' file
111222333 111
111222444 111
111222555 111
111222777 222
111222888 111
```